# Canvas mouse events delayed when using resized via CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I am playing around with a project to learn more about node.js & html canvases.

In my project I have a canvas that I want to keep a fixed bitmap size, but fill its containing div while maintaining its aspect ratio.

I have applied a size of 500x500 to my canvas element, and then applied the following style in CSS.

```
canvas {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Inside the javascript initially fill the canvas white so I get something like the below, so far so good.

[image]

I hook into the mouse events and use them to draw lines. I use the below function to correctly scale events to the canvas.

```
function  getMousePos(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); // abs. size of element

  var raw_x = evt.clientX||evt.touches[0].clientX;
  var raw_y = evt.clientY||evt.touches[0].clientY;

  var min_dimension = Math.min(rect.width,rect.height);
  var x_offset = 0.5*(rect.width-min_dimension);
  var y_offset = 0.5*(rect.height-min_dimension);

  return {
    x: ((raw_x - rect.left - x_offset) / min_dimension) * canvas.width,
    y: ((raw_y - rect.top - y_offset) / min_dimension) * canvas.height
  }
}
```

This works, however when drawing on the canvas when the mouse moves over a band on the right side of the image it doesn't update until the mouse leaves the band. The band is the same size as the space on the left of the canvas so I think its related but I don't know how to investigate. I have no Issues if I resize the window till there is no space on either side of the canvas bitmap (and performance is considerably faster). The below gif should make things more clear.

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion on what could be causing this, or a better way for me to achieve the same effect.

Note: I am running chrome version 80.0.3987.149

Comment: band??? No idea what that is??? If you are listening to mouse events from the canvas and the mouse moves over another element (depending on how you have set up) you may not get the mouse events for the canvas.You can listen at higher level (say at the document and check `event.target` to see if its the canvas) or you can turn of mouse events for overlaying elements using the CSS rule `pointer-events: none;` If needed you can assign the rule on mouse down and remove it on pen up.

Comment: They bands I am referring to are the grey bands in my image, they are effectively inside the canvas element but outside the canvas bitmap. The be clear the grey bands are what I want, however when they appear there is a correspondingly sized invisible band on the right side of my image where drawing misbehaves.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this, I couldn't find a good solution, beyond using JavaScript to resize the element when the window resize event occurs.